# get the count of dayname Failed - Laravel 9

Tags: mysql, laravel, chart.js, laravel-9

For my case , I have a data table contains a timestamps data call "created_at" , right  now , it want to get the count of the dayname of the time stamp

so ideally it will be like

[image]

and I like to save it on the array for me to pass the data to may chart.js chart
so what i do is

```
 $getdate = DB::table('watchlists')
      ->select('created_at')
      ->get();

      $getweekday = Carbon::parse($getdate)->format('l');
         $dayarray=[];
      if($getweekday =='Monday')
      {
          $mondaycount = Carbon::parse($getdate)->count();

          $dayarray=[0];
      }
      elseif($getweekday =='Tuesday')
      {
        $tuesday = Carbon::parse($getdate)->count();
        $dayarray=[1];
      }
      elseif($getweekday =='Wednesday')
      {
        $wednesday = Carbon::parse($getdate)->count();
        $dayarray=[2];
      }
      elseif($getweekday =='Thursday')
      {
        $thursday = Carbon::parse($getdate)->count();
        $dayarray=[3];
      }
      elseif($getweekday =='Friday')
      {
        $firday = Carbon::parse($getdate)->count();
        $dayarray=[4];
      }
      elseif($getweekday =='Saturday')
      {
        $saturday = Carbon::parse($getdate)->count();
        $dayarray=[5];
      }
      elseif($getweekday =='Sunday')
      {
        $sunday = Carbon::parse($getdate)->count();
        $dayarray=[6];
      }
```

```
<script>
        const ctx = document.getElementById('chart1').getContext('2d');
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Visitor Volume by weekday',
                    data: [{{ $dayarray}}],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

but when i try to run the code it gives the error of

```
Could not parse '[{"created_at":"2022-06-24 18:50:05"},{"created_at":"2022-06-26 13:24:42"},{"created_at":"2022-06-24 18:50:05"},{"created_at":"2022-06-26 13:24:42"},{"created_at":"2022-06-26 13:24:42"},{"created_at":"2022-06-26 13:24:42"}]': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ([{&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2022-06-24 18:50:05&quot;},{&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2022-06-26 13:24:42&quot;},{&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2022-06-24 18:50:05&quot;},{&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2022-06-26 13:24:42&quot;},{&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2022-06-26 13:24:42&quot;},{&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2022-06-26 13:24:42&quot;}]) at position 0 ([): Unexpected character
```

I like to ask what is the error in the code , did I miss anything?

PS. I would also like to ask how to pass the data to the charts . i have a premade charts

Comment: `parse` is for parsing a single date as a string and you are passing a collection of objects to it which is getting converted to json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array `reduce()` function for this purpose. It is a php array function that you can find docs in [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and also for [laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-reduce)

```php
$dayCounts = DB::table('watchlists')
      ->select('created_at')
      ->get()
      ->reduce(function ($car, $item) {
          $day       = Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('l');
          $car[$day] = ($car[$day] ?? 0) + 1;
          return $car;
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but honestly im not really understand that much on this, can yoy elarborate more about this code?

Comment: Using `array_reduce` enable you to get your favorable result out of an array. In your case, I have parsed every item of the query result collection and have counted their days. I used `$car` parameter for achieving this as it is persisted throughout every iteration. I suggest you read more about this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ,  your code is perfectly working . Aprreciated for that ... Yes i will try to read more on the documenation